# How to set up the terminal for VSC?

Tags: javascript, terminal

I have been working on an online code-program, since there is a terminal I haven't face the problem of working with the terminal on VSC. I'm working on Javascript to solve a problem, however, frequently I want to know how all is it going; but, actually I have no idea of how to work with the terminal, even afterward I have browsed for the web and also follow the steps to install Gitbash and Node, my computer didn't respond to a symply command as console.log(). I don't know if all this info is shown on another page or something like that. So please, if you could help me I would be very glad.
Thank you!

Comment: The terminal is a bash terminal, not a nodejs repl. You might be looking for the debugging console?

Comment: Thank you for answered Bergi, but actually I'm introducing on all this world of programming, so clearly I don't know. I only want to find the path so I could see that my code is function (e.i reflecting all this in the usual output you would expect when you hit run on Codecademy).

Comment: I believe VSCode comes with an integrated terminal. Here are the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal). After you have your project folder open in VSCode, you can open the terminal by using one of the methods specified in the docs. It should open up a panel at the bottom of your VSCode window. If you have Node.js installed on your computer and have your Javascript file directly inside of your folder, you can execute your Javascript code by typing `node theNameOfMyJavascriptFile.js`. If you're still having trouble, you can use [Repl.it](https://repl.it/).

Comment: @poppa Sounds like you want to [launch a debugging session](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) or [run a custom task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks).

Comment: I'll try it @Khan, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I think so Bergi, I'll review the documentation. Surely with all these will be fine. I appreciate a lot you aid. Thank you again @Bergi.